# chart.js version 4.4 shows additional scales on both axes, how to remove these?

Tags: chart.js, linechart, angular16

[In the Image as you can see on the left side of the y axis there is another scale which goes from 0 to 1 I want to remove this scale.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L5Yg.png)

I thought adding a title to the graph will make it go away but that does not work, as you can see in the image it still adds a scale from 0 to 1 on the left side of the title that says "No. of students". Kindly help me fix this problem. If you have a reference to a documents which addresses this problem please share it in the comments.

```
options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
        display: true,
      },
      title: {
        display: false
      },
      
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes:
      {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Year',
        },
        position: 'bottom',
        grid: {
          color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
          display: false,
          drawTicks: false
        },
        
      },
      yAxes:
      {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'No. of Students',
        },
        beginAtZero: true,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 5,
        },
        grid:{
          drawOnChartArea: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the configuration options I've added I tried playing around them but could not get the scale off.

Comment: Chart.js does not add by itself supplemental axes. You must've added them in the configuration object. You have to remove them.

Comment: Sir I have provided the options code in the question can you please help me out. @kikon

Comment: The simplest solution is to replace the ids for the scales in the options: from `xAxes` to `x` and from `yAxes` to `y` (i.e., replace `xAxes: {....` with `x: {....` and the same with `yAxes`). The default axes ids are `x` and `y`; setting properties for other ids than `x` and `y` results in the creation of additional axes, unless *all* datasets specify their `xAxisID` and `yAxisID` to the new axes. So, an alternative solution would be to keep current ids and set them as the axes ids, through `xAxisID: "xAxes"`, `yAxisID: "yAxes"` in each dataset, but that seems an unnecessary complication.